How do we test Riemann zeta zeros for simplicity?
I understand that we call a “simple zero” if the first derivative of the complex function $\neq 0$.
How does this apply to the zeros of the Riemann zeta?
I read that all known zeros are simple.
Taking the derivative of $\zeta(s) = \sum n^{-s}$ won’t work because this zeta is valid only for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$
We must be using one of the continued zeta functions. Which zeta function do we use to test that, for instance, the first zero, $\rho_1 = (0.5 + i14.134725\ldots)$ is simple?
How do we test that a Riemann zeta zero is simple?

The trivial zeroes are simple, see this post. In general, it is an open conjecture. It is discussed in this post, and other ones. This post should have an explanation how to see that the known zeroes are simple.

In this linked pdf on page 3, they differentiate Riemann's functional equation to show that trivial zeros are simple. I was looking the same for the non-trivial zeros. The linked posts and links in them do not have a similar computation. Can you sketch a proof to show how this is done? Thanks.

the known zeroes are found using the Hardy $Z$ function since that is real on the critical line and has same modulus (hence same zeroes) as zeta there; there is a very good approximation called Riemann Siegel there and one can compute values of $Z$ very accurately and for large $t$; in particular one finds where $Z$ changes sign with very large accuracy so there are the zeroes. A count using the known formula for all the nontrivial zeroes shows that they are simple and all of them until some large levels - so the computation is done quite indirectly

for more details, Edwards book on Riemann Zeta is the place to go

@Conrad Yes, I have the book in front of me, but not sure how to sift through all these "indirect computations" to find any specific derivative testing the simplicity of a zero. But let me ask you something else that I don't understand. What does "Hardy  function is real on the critical line" mean? Does it mean that the imaginary part is zero on the critical line? Why?

There is no specific derivative testing for the simplicity of the nontrivial zeroes - the way is done is much subtler; as for the Hardy function it takes only real values by construction
